# Install Hololens application from Microsoft Store with code

Tags: uwp, hololens, msix

I am looking a way to install an application from the Microsoft Store by code on Hololens 2. Using UWP API or Device portal API and assuming a valid account is already configured.

Any tip would be welcomed, thank you!

Comment: What except behavior that  you want. Do you means launch the Microsoft Store with app's install link then install with Microsoft Store?

Comment: I would like to avoid any user manipulation. If it using the Microsoft Store Application it is not a problem but I guess it is not possible to "command" this app (once it is launched) from another one?

Comment: Yep, the better way is use Microsoft Store app launch uri scheme to launch Microsoft Store app then click install button to install app.

Comment: So it's not possible to do the process 100% by code. Do you know how we can get the uri path of an app for Hololens Store? Thank you very much for you help :)
Edit: also is it possible to launch the uri from an other device (with the device portal for exemple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such api install app from Microsoft Store  by code (100%). But you could launch Microsoft Store app with app's product id then click install button manually. For more please refer [**Launch the Microsoft Store app**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app).

```
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9WZDNCRFHVJL"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to avoid any user manipulation then I think a different route you can look into if your devices are enrolled in MDM is using Required Apps. After you flash a device and go through set up, depending on who the first user is, the device is registered to that person and is registered with AzureAD.

Have all the users you want to automatically receive apps in a group. And then for each app, set it to be "Required" for that group. The apps will start automatically downloading when they finish set up.

https://learn.microsoft.com/mem/intune/apps/apps-deploy#assign-an-app